# Reactor Kafka consume messages synchronous and process them async

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

I'm quite new into the reactive world and using Spring Webflux + reactor Kafka.

```
        kafkaReceiver
                .receive()
//                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .doOnNext(a -> log.info("Reading message: {}", a.value()))
                .concatMap(kafkaRecord ->
                 //perform DB operation
                 //kafkaRecord.receiverOffset.ackwnowledge         
                )
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error", e))
                .retry()
                .subscribe();
```

I understood that in order to parallelise message consumption, I have to instantiate one KafkaReceiver for each partition but is it possible/recommended for a partition to read messages in a synchronous manner and process them async (including the manual acknowledge)?

So that this is the desired output:

```
Reading message:1
Reading message:2
Reading message:3
Reading message:4
Stored message 1 in DB + ack
Reading message:5
Stored message 2 in DB + ack
Stored message 5 in DB + ack
Stored message 3 in DB + ack
Stored message 4 in DB + ack
```

In case of errors, I'm thinking of publishing the record to a DLT.

I've tried with flatMap too, but it seems that the entire processing happens sequentially on a single thread. Also if I'm publishing to a new scheduler, the processing happens on a new single Thread.
If what I'm asking is possible, can someone please help me with a code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactor Kafka is built on top of `KafkaConsumer` API and polling cycle is separated from processing logic with backpreasure and pause consumer if required. By default, `KafkaReceiver` publishes fetched records on a `Schedulers.single` thread.

Now, depends on your logic, you could process data and commit offsets sequentially or in parallel. For concurrent processing you can use `flatMap` that by default, processes `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = 256` messages concurrently.

You could control concurrency `flatMap(item -> process(item), concurrency)` or use `concatMap` operator if you want to process sequentially. Check [flatMap(..., int concurrency, int prefetch)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-int-) for details.

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
    .flatMap(rec -> process(rec), concurrency)
```

### Kafka ordered vs unordered processing

Depending on use case there are several options.

**Ordered message processing**

In case message order is important and messages should be processed in the same sequence as they are sent by producer. Kafka guarantees message order per partition.

In Reactior Kafka you can do it by grouping data per partition and then process then sequentially

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
        .groupBy(message -> message.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
        .flatMap(partitions -> partitions.concatMap(this::process));
```

**Unordered message processing**

In case sequence is not imporant and messages could be processed in any order we could increase throughput by processing multiple messages in parallel.

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
        .flatMap(message -> process(message), concurrency);
```

Reactor kafka supports [out of order commits](https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/1.3.17-SNAPSHOT/reference/index.html#_out_of_order_commits) and the framework will defer the commits as needed, until any "gaps" are filled. This removes the need for applications to keep track of offsets and commit them in the right order.

In general, unordered message processing will support much higher throughput on a small number of partitions. For ordered message processing you would need to increase number of partitions to increase throughput. You can find some additional consideration here [how to increase message throughput](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75319529/9068895)

Let's consider example where processing logic is making remote http call using reactive `WebClient`.

```
private Mono<Void> process(ReceiverRecord<String, String> rec) {
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("https://postman-echo.com/post")
            .retrieve()
            .toBodilessEntity()
            .doOnNext(res -> log.info("processed: {}, partition: {}", rec.value(), rec.partition()))
            .then();
}
```

If you add logging, you would see that all records are received on `kafka-receiver-2` but processed on different `reactor-http-nio-#` threads. Note, that records are received in order per partition and respect concurrency. Here is a log with `concurrency = 5`.

```
20:46:31.003  [kafka-receiver-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-2, partition: 0
20:46:31.572  [kafka-receiver-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-7, partition: 0
20:46:31.574  [kafka-receiver-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-8, partition: 0
20:46:31.576  [kafka-receiver-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-0, partition: 2
20:46:31.579  [kafka-receiver-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-1, partition: 2
20:46:31.853  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-8, partition: 0
20:46:31.853  [reactor-http-nio-6] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-1, partition: 2
20:46:31.853  [reactor-http-nio-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-2, partition: 0
20:46:31.853  [reactor-http-nio-3] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-7, partition: 0
20:46:31.853  [reactor-http-nio-5] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-0, partition: 2
20:46:31.854  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-4, partition: 2
20:46:31.857  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-5, partition: 2
20:46:31.859  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-9, partition: 2
20:46:31.862  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-3, partition: 1
20:46:31.864  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - receive: value-6, partition: 1
20:46:31.908  [reactor-http-nio-2] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-9, partition: 2
20:46:31.908  [reactor-http-nio-3] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-5, partition: 2
20:46:31.913  [reactor-http-nio-5] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-3, partition: 1
20:46:31.913  [reactor-http-nio-6] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-6, partition: 1
20:46:31.937  [reactor-http-nio-4] INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - processed: value-4, partition: 2
```

Different reactive clients internally could use different thread pools. For example, for reactive redis (lettuce) it should be `lettuce-nioEventLoop-#`, for reactive mongo - `nioEventLoopGroup-#`.

It's important to note (*@PatPanda* thanks for correction) that if you don't have any async logic (delay, http calls or any other I/O bound reactive code), the subscription and execution will continue on the same thread.
To switch to another `Scheduler` we need to add `.subscribeOn` (e.g. `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())` or .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`) to the` process` function.

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
    .flatMap(rec -> process(rec).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()))
```

or configure the Supplier for a `Scheduler` on which records will be published

```
ReceiverOptions<K, V> subscription = ReceiverOptions.<K, V>create(consumerProperties)
       .schedulerSupplier(() -> Schedulers.newParallel("kafka-receiver", 3, false))
        .subscription(topics);
var receiver = KafkaReceiver.create(subscription);
```

Comment: Hello @Alex, do you have the code snippet for this output please? I am using the ```kafkaReceiver.receive().flatMap(message -> process(message), concurrency);``` with the value of concurrency from 1 to 100 (tested manually) on a 8 CPU machine. I am ALWAYS seeing ```INFO [c.e.d.KafkaConsumerTest] - process:``` on thread ```reactive-kafka-1``` as per the issue describe by author

Comment: @PatPanda you are right. forgot to mention that switch will not happen automatically until you have some async logic in the `process`. In my test I had async logic and processing was running on a parallel scheduler. Corrected the answer adding more info.

Comment: No problem @Alex. thank you for following up on this. I tried this: ```return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                .receive()
                .flatMap(rec -> {
                    LOGGER.info("process " + rec.value() + " process: " + rec.partition());
                    return reactiveElasticRepository.save(new ElasticPojo(LocalDateTime.now(), rec.key() + rec.partition(), rec.value()))
                            .map(__ -> rec.value())
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());
                });```

Comment: This is per definition a reactive I/O call (using elasticsearch reactive repository). However, all consumption, as well as database I/O are all happening on reactive-kafka-1 thread

Comment: @PatPanda In this case you don't need to switch to `parallel()`. As far as I remember `ReactiveElasticRepository` uses `WebClient` and processing will be switched to reactive thread pool anyway. In your example you are logging during subscription time that happens on the same thread but if you add log into  `.map(__ -> rec.value()) ` you should see different thread.

Comment: I am trying with ReactiveCassandraRepository, ReactiveMongoRepository and ReactiveRedisRepository, everything happens on the same thread. Do you have an example with some sort of reactive repository, some sort of processing, and some acknowledgement, as described in the question from original post please?

Comment: Try to add log to any operator following  async call (`doOnNext()`  or like  in your example, `.map(__ -> rec.value()) `)  and you should see different "reactive" thread. For example, for reactive redis (lettuce) it should be `lettuce-nioEventLoop-#`, for reactive mongo - `nioEventLoopGroup-#`

Comment: I think we might be getting away from the initial problem, which is: Reactor Kafka consume messages synchronous and process them async. In below code, the processing is not happening async

Comment: ```Flux<ElasticPojo> consume() {
        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
                .receive()
                .flatMap(rec -> {
                    LOGGER.info("process " + rec.value());
                    String s = processAsyncPlease(rec.value());
                    return reactiveRepository.save(new ElasticPojo(LocalDateTime.now(), s, s))
                            ;
                });
    }

    String processAsyncPlease(String one) {
        LOGGER.info("should happen on another thread, but it is not " + one);
        return one.toUpperCase();
    }```

Comment: You are still logging not at the right place. By default subscription is happening on the same thread but if you are calling reactive/async API (web client, reactive db call, ...) processing will start on the same thread but complete on the different reactive scheduler because all async drivers typically using event loops to execute non-blocking I/O. Let me try to modify the code to show the point where you need to log

Comment: @PatPanda added example that uses `WebClient` but for other reactive clients (mongo, redis, ..) behavior will be the same.