# SpringBoot with REACTOR kafka : increase message consumption thorughput on a 2CPUs pod

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

Small question regarding a SpringBoot 3 app with reactor kafka please.

I have a small reactive kafka consumer app, which consumes messages from kafka and processes the message.

The app is consuming one topic `the-topic` which has **three partitions**.

The app is dockerized, and for resource consumption limit reason, the app can only use 2CPUs (please bear with me on that one). And to make things more difficult, I am allowed to only have **one unique instance** of this app running.

The app is very straightforward:

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

```
@Configuration
public class MyKafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public KafkaReceiver<String, String> reactiveKafkaConsumerTemplate(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        kafkaProperties.setBootstrapServers(List.of("my-kafka.com:9092"));
        kafkaProperties.getConsumer().setGroupId("should-i-do-something-here");
        final ReceiverOptions<String, String> basicReceiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());
        basicReceiverOptions.subscription(Collections.singletonList("the-topic"));
        return new DefaultKafkaReceiver<>(ConsumerFactory.INSTANCE, basicReceiverOptions);
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class MyConsumer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver;


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        myConsumer().subscribe();
    }

    public Flux<String> myConsumer() {
        return kafkaReceiver.receive()
                .flatMap(oneMessage -> consume(oneMessage))
                .doOnNext(abc -> System.out.println("successfully consumed {}={}" + abc))
                .doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println("something bad happened while consuming : {}" + throwable.getMessage()));
    }

    private Mono<String> consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> oneMessage) {
        // this first line is a heavy in memory computation which transforms the incoming message to a data to be saved.
        // it is very intensive computation, but has been tested NON BLOCKING by different tools, and takes 1 second :D
        String transformedStringCPUIntensiveNonButNonBLocking = transformDataNonBlockingWithIntensiveOperation(oneMessage);
        //then, just saved the correct transformed data into any REACTIVE repository :)
        return myReactiveRepository.save(transformedStringCPUIntensiveNonButNonBLocking);
    }

}
```

If I understand project reactor correctly, and due to my resource limitation, I will have at most 2 reactor cores.

The **consume method here has been tested non-blocking**, but takes one second to deal with the message.

Therefore, will I only be able to consume 2 messages per second? (hopefully not)

The messages can be consumed in any order, I wish to just maximize the throughput with this single app.

May I ask how could I maximize parallelism / throughput on this app with those constraints please?

Thank you

Comment: So, your consume method is CPU intensive ? If it is, there's not much you can do, because it requires to use CPU full time to do the job. But, if you see that your CPU is not fully used, then it might be that your consume function is blocking, in one way or another. Can you provide some information about what *consume* do ?  For it to be non-blocking, it means that it only perform in-memory computation. Otherwise, if it sends data to a database or a webservice, it is blocking.

Answer (score 5):

We could apply [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) to calculate required concurrency for handling required throughput.

`workers >= throughput x latency`, in our case `workers` is a number of messages processed in parallel

For example, to handle 100 messages per sec with 60 sec latency we would need to process 100 x 60 = 6000 concurrently. In "traditional" blocking app we would need the same number of threads. In reactive app the same workload could be handled by several threads only and, as result, much less memory. Even if a message takes 30-60 sec to process, thread will not be blocked because all IO operations are async. To scale processing you need to decrease the latency or increase concurrency.

In our case we need to process 6000 in parallel. With 3 partitions you could have 3 consumers processing 2000 messages in parallel each.

By default, `flatMap` is processing `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = 256` messages in parallel but you can make this configurable.

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
    .flatMap(oneMessage -> consume(oneMessage), concurrency)
```

It's really hard to say how many messages one app can handle and you would need to run a load test to understand max throughput. Try to maximize this number to understand your limits looking at metrics. In case app could not handle such load, you would need to increase number of partitions and deploy more consumers.

Ultimately, your goal is to process more messages than you produce. If producers send 2 messages per second then you don't need high concurrency (2 * 60 = 120).

There are other variables to consider - message size, throughput of the downstream system, limits of other components. For example, WebClient/Netty has a default limit of 500 concurrent connections. Sometimes you even need to "slow down" consumers to don't overload downstream services.

Comment: Very clear explanation, upvote

Comment: Hey @Alex, based on what you said, "To scale processing you need to decrease the latency or increase concurrency." and "3 partitions you could have 3 consumers". Suppose I cannot decrease latency (please bear with me) and I am only able to have 1 consumer only (please bear with me), what can I do to further improve the processing please? Are you suggesting, (with supposition of the constraints), I can try to increase the variable ```concurrency``` in flatMap to a bigger number than 256? Will I gain any performance if I use a Scheduler (note, the consume method has been proven NON blocking).

Comment: I believe that What Alex trying to say is that you have firstly to load test the concurency to discover your system max capabilities, theorically Yes, increasing the Concurency will result on more resolved messages. but you should first define you'r system maximum concurency wich is set by default to minimal 256.

Comment: What is your current producer rate? Ultimately your goal is to process more messages than you produce. If producer send 2 messages per second then you don't need high concurrency (2 * 60 = 120) that is not really high. Based on our experience 256 is not high number and you can increase it. There are other variable you need to consider - message size, throughput of the downstream system. For example, you need to make sure that your database could handle required writes per sec. Based on our experience 256 is not high number and some of our services process 1000+ messages concurrently.

Comment: To reiterate, to find our you "speed of light", increase concurrency and load tests until your service could not handle it (look at CPU usage and other metrics). Reactor should not be a concern here. Usually It's more about processing logic and downstream systems.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process messages from a Flux publisher in a parallel manner you have to use `flatMap` operator, because `map` operator operates in a synchronous way by requesting items by 1.

When you are using the `flatMap` operator you can rely on Reactor and let him control the concurrency or you can specify the desired concurrency via **concurrency** parameter (i.e. `flatMap(it -> consume(), YOUR_CONCURRENCY_VALUE)`

**If your `consume()` method is not a publisher:**

You can wrap it in a Mono by using `Mono.fromCallable()` and publish it on a scheduler that is designed of blocking tasks:

```
.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
```

But better rewrite all consumer code to the reactive types otherwise you lose the benefits of using the reactor.

Comment: Thank you @Vladen for your answer! the consume method is non-blocking already (blockhound tested). What would be the magic value for YOUR_CONCURRENCY_VALUE on a 2CPUs in order to maximize throughput please?

Comment: 256 is the default value for the concurrency of flatMap, but the correct value for your use case can be found just by doing tests